# Current year (by default) for the selector in view (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to the AngularJS. Here is my `$scope` of years for the selector in html:

```
//get it from the backend 
$scope.years = ['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'];
```

here is my html where I use this `$scope`:

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="yearFromSelector">
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

when I run my app, I see an empty selector (with years inside) by default:

[image]

but I need to default selector shows the current year (with the other years inside). Please advise how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code.

In controller:

```
$scope.years = ['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'];
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var index = $scope.years.indexOf(currentYear.toString());

$scope.yearFromSelector = $scope.years[index];
```

and HTML:

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="yearFromSelector">
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

or

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="yearFromSelector" ng-options="year as year for year in years">
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
<select ng-init="yearFromSelector='2017'" name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="yearFromSelector">
    <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Controller:

```
$scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Add this to View:

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="yearFromSelector">
    <option ng-selected="year == currentYear" ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified answer:

JS:

`$scope.yearFromSelector = new Date().getFullYear().toString();`

HTML:

```
 <select ng-model="yearFromSelector" ng-options="year as year for year in years">
  </select>
```

Comment: Sorry, but simplified answer may help someone who is looking for similar solution easily.

Comment: If there is no option with ng-repeat, then he can try this. But once accepted, most users will see the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to implement using angularjs. You don't need to use value="{{year}}" because you are already defining the actual value using ng-model

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    $scope.years = ['2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="thisYear">
    <option ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```